# How to set up Auditor in Hyperledger Fabric network v0.6

Tags: networking, audit, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am lookinG around to find the way to set up auditors within hyperledger fabric network to detect if any transaction is illegally changed ,but I cannot find any way yet.
Appreciate if any useful docs or configuration is indicate.
**Fabric v0.6**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperledger Fabric How to set up Auditor in non-permission Network and permission network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624431/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-set-up-auditor-in-non-permission-network-and-permissio)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule (and, admittedly, this generalizes things somewhat) you can't *detect* illegally changed transactions in a Blockchain platform. You *avoid* illegal transactions and post facto changes by making the P2P system to run consensus on the incoming transactions and the current state of the Ledger (transaction log). As long as the "majority" (what this exactly means depends on a number of factors) behaves correctly, malicious activity is rejected. On the other hand, when enough peers are malevolent, they *can* introduce certain "illegal changes" (although in a permissioned Blockchain, not arbitrary changes, as long as the CA infrastructure is not broken and private keys are not compromised). This is why maintaining consensus correctness is crucial (e.g. by having a huge number of nodes with a vested interest in behaving correctly - see Bitcoin). You may think of regularly backing up the current ledger in your own "peer" to catch the point when the system "becomes compromised", but there are many murky details that make this a questionable idea.

There may still be need for an audit role in a business setting - but then this auditor will perform application-level checks (the ones not built into the chaincode) and queries (e.g. for regulatory evaluation purposes). However, such a node is simply a Blockchain client, not even necessarily a peer.

Comment: OK, Thank for your response.
I wonder, anyway around that I can change data in transaction of blockchain. I really want to know how the network is detect one transaction is not correct.

Comment: The specific answers to this are actually much more involved than what is customary for Stack Overflow. You should turn to the (generally very nice and helpful) community with this, see https://www.hyperledger.org/community (maybe after going through the documentation again)